# Is it possible to convert Image pdf in PDFTables package

Tags: pdftables

I am trying to convert PDF using PDFtables package which is an image of text, that is when we open the PDF in a PDF viewer and we cannot select words or lines with the cursor.

Whether there is any solution for converting this type of file using PDFtables package??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question (or at least it's really unclear how it's a programming question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot do this with PDFTables. You will need to run your PDF through an OCR converter first before running it through PDFTables.